# Serving NGINX with DJANGO on Ubuntu

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to Run my `django(1.8)` project on `Nginx` server since it is much faster. I am able to run by using `uwsgi --ini` commands to setup socket. so what I wants to do is by running `NGINX` alone want to run my `django` project, Is there any way to do that? Well the socket created by `uwsgi` is removing automatically when `uwsgi --ini` command ends.

```
NGINX config and .ini ia as shown below :

# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {

     server unix:///var/www/html/vir/crum/crumbs.sock;

}

    # configuration of the server
    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      8000;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name .localhost.com; 
        charset     utf-8;


        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /var/www/html/alteryx_vir/crum/media;  
        }

        location /static {
            alias /var/www/html/vir/crum/static;  

        }

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  django;

            /var/www/html/vir/crum/uwsgi_params; 
        }
    }

    >>> uwsgi.ini file :

    # mysite_uwsgi.ini file
    [uwsgi]

    # Django-related settings
    # the base directory (full path)
    chdir           = /var/www/html/vir/crumb/
    # Django's wsgi file
    module          = crum.wsgi
    # the virtualenv (/alteryx_vir/)
    home            = /var/www/html/alteryx_vir/
    # process-related settings
    # master
    master          = true
    # maximum number of worker processes
    processes       = 10
    # the socket (use the full path to be safe
    socket          = 
    /var/www/html/alteryx_vir/crum/crum.sock
    #socket           = var/run/uwsgi/crum.sock


    # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
    chmod-socket    = 666
    # clear environment on exit
    vacuum          = true
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Atlast i could automate everything byusing UWSGI EMPEROR mode.
Now All commands can be automate all you needs to do is to start NGINX server.

Emperror Mode:

Edit /etc/rc.local and add:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi-emperor.log
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking doesn't make sense. The socket is for communication between nginx and uWSGI. If uWSGI is not running, there would be nothing on the other end of the socket and nothing serving your app.

You need both nginx and uWSGI.

Comment: yea i was miss guided then thanx for your information mr. @Daniel  so how can i automate . I dont want to run some command to start uwsgi. Hope you got my point

Comment: Like any server process (including nginx itself), you use your distro's process manager - eg systemd or upstart - or something like supervisord.